# Retaining clickable areas that fall under an area with negative margin offset with padding

Tags: html, css, position

If I've had to use a negative margin and then offset with padding to position elements on web page, how do I make any areas that appear under this space still clickable (like the screenshot below shows)?

[image]

I have tried using `z-index` to make the 'join our loyalty scheme' banner stack below everything else but that doesn't seem to be working...

I tried replicating the issue in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9ohc1y4/) but as per the below screenshot, the links underneath this space are clickable still so something is different between the website and the jsfiddle example obviously but can anyone point me to the quickest solution to rectify this if z-index isn't the answer?

[image]

Comment: Really, you can't reproduce the issue with your example? Then you must be missing something that's affecting your link. did you post ***every css rule*** that links to this item?

Comment: Please include the styling that makes your 'links' appear as they do in your screenshot.

Comment: Well, okay, but it will be an absolute ton of markup and styles as I've just extracted from a deeper level the relevant bits. I thought someone might be able to say 'this usually happens because of x, y or z' from what I posted.

Comment: Ok,  *'this usually happens because of bad programming practises'*. Seriously, though, negative margins *really* aren't the way to go with this sort of structure... The fact is, why does it need to be 'overlapping' in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I agree but I did some funky stuff with a logo I made round and then only showed the top half. Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qhcqsj6/) to see what I mean (which does replicate the issue by the way). It got a bit messy due to the logo but I couldn't find another way of overlapping the bottom half of the logo... See what you think.

Comment: I can see what you've *attempted* here. You've started by trying to create desktop, then gone 'lets make it responsive as well' halfway through, then gone "need media queries, better add them". So realistically, you've been working all over the show. What you *should* do is create one, then the other. Trying to do both at once doesn't make this easy. You've got a good idea here, you've just gone about it the wrong way IMHO.

Comment: In terms of the 'logo', you could've placed it in a wrapper div, given it a defined height, and then set overflow to hidden (so no overlapping needed).

Comment: Let me try your suggestion as if I can find another way to handle the logo then it solves about 500 other issues which all require illogical styling to fix. Thanks man.

Comment: Tried this but then I can't get the logo to overlap the black bar at the top because I have set it to overflow hidden. Tried z-index stacking again in this instance but no joy.